# iOS App Artwork PNG - Shall I Strip Metadata?

Tags: android, ios, png, design-guidelines

The [Android developer icon design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) state that

> When saving image assets, remove unnecessary metadata

In the Apple iOS guidelines I cannot find any similar statement.

Is it advisable to strip the metadata of my PNG Artwork for my iOS app, nevertheless, e.g. to optimize bandwidth, or is it a minor issue? Do you do that? If so, what tool can I use for batch processing?